# How to show Google map in my application when no connection

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I want to show my Google map in my Android application even when the phone is not connected to wifi or 3G. Also I want to add markers to Google map. Is there any method to do that? This is my code of my map:

```
if (googleMap == null) {
    googleMap = ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: When there is no internet connection you need to fetch your location from database. For that you need to store your locations in to database with intervals using GPS.

Comment: i stored location into database , now i want to display the whole map in my activity when no connection, is this possible ?

Comment: Yes there is offline map code project https://github.com/mapswithme/api-android

Comment: this code requires downloading maps.me app, is there any method to do that without download any other app ??

Answer (score 1):

Saving a map is pretty simple — to start, move the map to the location that you want to save for offline use. Then simply touch the **Search bar** at the top of the app, scroll to the bottom of the interface and tap **Save map to use offline**. If you searched for a location rather than manually finding the area, tap the bar at the bottom, then the **menu button** in the top right corner and tap **Save offline map**. In either case you'll then be taken back to the area of the map you were previously on, with a new interface.

[image]

Move around the map to select the area you want to save — the app will save everything on the map that's in view, and nothing more. You'll notice that there's a limit on the area you are allowed to save — it's enough room to get you an entire city or two, but you won't be saving whole states or regions with this method. Once you've found the area you want to save, tap **Save** at the bottom of the screen and then fill in a name for the saved area when the dialog box appears.

To see the state of your offline maps and manage them, swipe in from the left edge of the app and tap **Your places** at the top of the menu. Scroll down to the bottom and select **View all and manage** in the offline maps section. Here you'll see all of your currently-available offline maps, their expiration dates and their size in megabytes. You can tap on any selection to be taken to that saved area, or you can tap the **menu** button on the right to rename, update or delete the saved map.

Also , you can see...
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNlleczyPjs